# Store and keep the value of a number through loops in an animation node loop

Tags: animation-nodes

I would like to know if there is a way i could store a number through animation node loops, to incrementially add some value to it, without it beeing reinitialized every loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is.

The **Reassign Loop Parameter** node allows you to pass a value to the next iteration of the loop. You can create it in the advanced settings of the *Loop Input* node.

[image]

In this example I also made it so that the *Sum* socket is an output of the loop instead of an input.